# sql oracle count occurrence for date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a chunk of data of drugs and date prescribed
One drug may be prescribed more than once in the same month

i need to list the details only if the drug has been prescribed more than 3 times per month
i am bad with the date query honestly

```
select Tradename as Drug, TO_CHAR(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') as Date_Prescribe
from PRESCRIPTION
group by TradeName
having count(PrescDT) > 3;
```

Is giving me an error "not a GROUP BY expression" and the results are wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work :

```
select Tradename as Drug, TO_CHAR(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') as Date_Prescribe
    from PRESCRIPTION
    group by TradeName,to_char(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') 
    having to_char(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY')>3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Tradename as Drug, TO_CHAR(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') as Date_Prescribe
from PRESCRIPTION
group by TradeName, TO_CHAR(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY')
having count(*) > 3;
```

Instead of TO_CHAR you might use `TRUNC(PrescDT,'MM')` instead, should be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

With CTE Data:

```
with prescription as (
  select 'advil' as tradename, TO_DATE('04-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'advil' as tradename, TO_DATE('04-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'advil' as tradename, TO_DATE('04-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'advil' as tradename, TO_DATE('06-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'tylenol' as tradename, TO_DATE('09-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'advil' as tradename, TO_DATE('04-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'tylenol' as tradename, TO_DATE('08-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual UNION ALL
  select 'morphine' as tradename, TO_DATE('10-2015', 'MM-YYYY') as PrescDT from dual 
)
select tradename as Drug, PrescDt as Date_Prescribe
from prescription
group by tradename, prescdt
having count(prescdt) > 3
;
```

Output:

```
DRUG   DATE_PRESCRIBE
advil   04-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`select Tradename as Drug, TO_CHAR(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') as Date_Prescribe, count(PrescDT)
    from PRESCRIPTION
    group by TradeName,to_char(PrescDT,'MM-YYYY') 
    where count(PrescDT)>3`